# How to create channels with Spring 4 annotation based?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to create a socket channel with a rendezvous queue where a client and server can exchange a simple message.

But I already fail to convert the following xml to annotation based spring-4 configuration:

```
<int:channel id="rendezvousChannel"/>
    <int:rendezvous-queue/>
</int:channel>
```

How would this look like in spring 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:

```
@Bean
public PollableChannel rendezvousChannel() {
   return new RendezvousChannel();
}
```

Can you explain why it was an issue for you to find the solution from your side?

Any XML component is backed by some Java class anyway and most cases their names reflect the XML component names.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably confused by the `int:channel` xml.