# TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean does not support circular references?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to create a simple `TcpInboundGateway` using `spring`.

But the following does not work:

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class MyEndpoint {
    @Bean
    public TcpInboundGateway gateway() throws Exception {
        TcpInboundGateway gate = new TcpInboundGateway();
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
        fact.setType("server");
        fact.setPort(5555);
        gate.setConnectionFactory(fact.getObject());
        gate.setRequestChannel(new RendezvousChannel());
        return gate;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: org.springframework.integration.ip.config.TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean does not support circular references
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.getEarlySingletonInstance(AbstractFactoryBean.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractFactoryBean.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 31 more
```

What might be missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to

```
@Bean
public TcpInboundGateway gateway(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
    TcpInboundGateway gate = new TcpInboundGateway();
    gate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    gate.setRequestChannel(new RendezvousChannel());
    return gate;
}

@Bean
public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean connectionFactory() {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    fact.setType("server");
    fact.setPort(5555);
    return fact;
}
```

Spring has a specific way of handling `FactoryBean` instances and your `gateway` bean breaks it by invoking `getObject` before the `TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean` is initialized (you could also call `afterPropertiesSet` to initialize inline). With the code above, you let Spring take care of the initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood a bit the JavaConfig concepts. Please, read more Spring Framework [Manual Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java).

The answer to your particular case: any `FactoryBean` must be configured as a separate `@Bean` and references like `method argument injection`:

```
@Bean
public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean connectionFactory() {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fact = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    fact.setType("server");
    fact.setPort(5555);
    return fact;
}

@Bean
public TcpInboundGateway gateway(AbstractConnectionFactory connectionFactory) throws Exception {
   TcpInboundGateway gate = new TcpInboundGateway();
   gate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
   gate.setRequestChannel(new RendezvousChannel());
   return gate;
}
```

As well as the `RendezvousChannel` as a bean from you separate question: [How to create channels with Spring 4 annotation based?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349174/how-to-create-channels-with-spring-4-annotation-based).